# How do you change the external editor in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I set it to paint and I do not remember how, I want to switch it to paint.net.

I've been looking and can't see where this setting is located. Thanks.

Comment: Might be under Preferences -> External Tools?

Comment: That's where I was looking originally haha

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nevermind I found it. In case anyone else is looking for this later here is a screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is old, but I thought I'd help because I couldn't find an answer to my situation. I was unable to set the image editor executable path using the Android Studio Settings menu. I had to edit the actual config file.

For anyone wondering, the config file should be

**AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.*X*\options\images.support.xml**

In my case, because I use the beta version of Android Studio 4.2, the part in the path that says AndroidStudio4.**X** was AndroidStudio4.2 for me.

Make sure Android Studio is closed for this.
(Not sure if it actually matters, but just incase.)
Open that file with a text editor like Notepad++ and add this line:

**<setting name="ExternalEditor.executablePath" value="PATH TO YOUR EDITOR" />**

When you're done, your images.support.xml file should look like this:
[images.support.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4SBJ.png)

Answer (score 2):

For Mac users, you can set the path by going to Preferences -> Editor -> Images -> External Editor. Then set the path to the app. For instance, the path to Photoshop might be /Applications/Adobe Photoshop CC 2015/Adobe Photoshop CC 2015.app

Comment: Don't know why you got down voted; this is accurate for Mac users and helpful.